# What is the closest stack-exchange site to ask about which new phone to buy?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I would like to ask about the different phones and plans that google has, but I am not sure which site to use for that.  Is there a site for that sort of a question?

Comment: Why don't you go on Area 51 and take a look?

Comment: It is unlikely that a shopping recommendations question is going to be on-topic on any StackExchange site.  However, you might get away with a question about a certain phone's specific features on Android.SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe there's none. gadgets.stackexchange would have been the closest, but it's been closed.

Anyway, most SE sites have a "this is not a place for shopping recommendation" rule in their FAQ.